# How to set global setting ellipsoid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ellipsoid

Is it possible to define ellipsoid (None/Planimetric) into QGIS environment, not only for Project environment?

I use calculations without ellipsoid, but sometimes I forget to make ellipsoid as None/Planimetric.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Calculations can be planimetric or geodesic related to the project ellipsoid. How are you performing your calculations?

Comment: I use EPSG 3346 without any additional ellipsoid (Non Planimetric). And if I forget to change ellipsoid to Non Planimetric, I get wrong calculated area (I compared it to ArcMap calculations). So I would like to make Non Planimetric as default ellipsoid, but cannot find place to do this.

Comment: That setting appears to be available only at the project level, not as a global setting. You could make a feature request. As a workaround, save a blank project with the setting (ellipsoid: none/planimetric). When you want to start a new project, open that blank ("template") project and save it with a new name.

Comment: @csk  thanks for advice. I think I will need to use it :) And make a feature request :)

Comment: How are you performing the area calculation? If you are doing from an expression, `$area` returns the ellipsoidal area related to the project ellipsoid and units, but `area( $geometry)` returns always planimetric area, related to the layer projection and units.

Comment: About templates, you can configure the default project in *Settings - Options - General - Project files*.

Comment: Combining @GabrielDeLuca's tips with my suggestion, I think there's actually a complete solution to your question, and probably no need to request a feature (although you can of course do so if you think there's a way to improve QGIS). I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The setting to use no ellipsoid for measurements isn't *directly* available as a global default setting for all projects. However, you can achieve the same effect by creating a template project with the desired settings (thanks to [Gabriel de Luca](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/133276/gabriel-de-luca) for this method).

1. Open a new project. Set the measurement ellipsoid to none/planimetric in the Project Properties window.

   [image]
2. In the Settings menu > Options | General window, choose "set current project as default" and "Create new project from default project.

[image]

Per another suggestion by Gabriel de Luca, you can also perform a planimetric area measurement in any project in the Field Calculator. Use the layer's projection and units, with the function `area( $geometry)` instead of `$area`.